# Keep the image after collapse the layout in coordinator layout and set min height

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, appbar, coordinator-layout

I am working in `collapseToolbarLayout`, in the design in the `appBar` it should be an image in the bottom anchor of the appBar (most of the designs put a `floatingActionButton` .. here I am using an image) I need partially collapse as I scroll up, but not completely. so I get some solution to set a min height from this [custom height for appBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41438994/create-custom-appbarlayout-child-with-minimum-height)

I tried one solution and its work, but, when I scroll up totally the image has been cut and the toolbar disappear , how to make the image stay as it is and not cut, in case of `floatingActionButton` the button disappear if you understand what I mean in my case which is an image I don't want it to disappear nor been cut

see this image to understand what is happen 
[image: the image of the logo is cut]

what I want is to keep the image like this here and also with the toolbar 
[image]

here is the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/pink"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:paddingBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/offerNameTxt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                android:text="Get a Pizza Free"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="34sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/descTitTxt"
                style="@style/AppTheme"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_below="@+id/offerNameTxt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Description"
                />


            <TextView android:id="@+id/offerDescTxt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/descTitTxt"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:letterSpacing="0.03"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="12sp"
                android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Rutrum 
      placerat habitant in eget. Enim elementum in sed lorem nisi purus pharetra. Suscipit 
      pellentesque nibh interdum ultrices enim, amet libero gravida scelerisque Rutrum 
      placerat."
                />


            <View
                android:id="@+id/line"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/offerDescTxt"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:alpha="0.4"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/socialMediaLayout"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/line"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/abc_vector_test"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"/>



            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/socialMediaLayout"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                    android:text=" Contact"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                    android:text=" Contact"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                    android:text=" Contact"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                    android:text=" Contact"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                    android:text=" Contact"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                    android:text=" Contact"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                    android:text=" Contact"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                    android:text=" Contact"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                    android:text=" Contact"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                    android:text=" Contact"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                    android:text=" Contact"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                    android:text=" Contact"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                    android:text=" Contact"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                    android:text=" Contact"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                    android:text=" Contact"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                    android:text=" Contact"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                    android:text=" Contact"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                    android:text=" Contact"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                    android:text=" Contact"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                    android:text=" Contact"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                    android:text=" Contact"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                    android:text=" Contact"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                    android:text=" Contact"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                    android:text=" Contact"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <om.metamorph.mycollapsingdemo.CustomCollapseLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:minHeight="100dp"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/expandedImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="@drawable/immmg"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:alpha="0.8"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TitleTxt"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                        android:gravity="bottom|center"
                        android:text="Pizza Hut"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </RelativeLayout>

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        </om.metamorph.mycollapsingdemo.CustomCollapseLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|start"
        android:src="@drawable/img22" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and here the MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ImageView fab = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fab.bringToFront();
    AppBarLayout mAppBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    mAppBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        boolean isShow = false;
        int scrollRange = -1;

        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {


            /**
             * Collapsed
             */
            if (Math.abs(verticalOffset) == appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange()) {
                fab.animate().scaleX((float)0.4).setDuration(3000);
                fab.animate().scaleY((float)0.4).setDuration(3000);
                fab.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(0);

                /**
                 * Expanded
                 */
            } else if (verticalOffset == 0) {
                fab.animate().scaleX((float)1).setDuration(100);
                fab.animate().scaleY((float)1).setDuration(100);
                fab.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(0);
                /**
                 * Somewhere in between
                 */
            } else {
                final int scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
                float offsetFactor = (float) (-verticalOffset) / (float) scrollRange;
                float scaleFactor = 1F - offsetFactor * .5F;
                fab.animate().scaleX(scaleFactor);
                fab.animate().scaleY(scaleFactor);
            }
        }
    });

}
}
```

and this the custom collapse layout class that I used to fix the height to what I want,

```
public class CustomCollapseLayout extends FrameLayout {
    private static final String TAG = "CollapsingImageLayout";

    private WindowInsetsCompat mLastInsets;

    private int mImageTopExpanded;


    private int mImageTopCollapsed;


    private OnOffsetChangedListener mOnOffsetChangedListener;

    public CustomCollapseLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CustomCollapseLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CustomCollapseLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        mImageTopCollapsed = getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.image_top_margin_collapsed);


        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(this,
                new androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener() {
                    @Override
                    public WindowInsetsCompat onApplyWindowInsets(View v, WindowInsetsCompat insets) {
                        return setWindowInsets(insets);
                    }
                });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        // Add an OnOffsetChangedListener if possible
        final ViewParent parent = getParent();
        if (parent instanceof AppBarLayout) {
            if (mOnOffsetChangedListener == null) {
                mOnOffsetChangedListener = new OnOffsetChangedListener();
            }
            ((AppBarLayout) parent).addOnOffsetChangedListener(mOnOffsetChangedListener);
        }

        // We're attached, so lets request an inset dispatch
        ViewCompat.requestApplyInsets(this);
    }


    private WindowInsetsCompat setWindowInsets(WindowInsetsCompat insets) {
        if (mLastInsets != insets) {
            mLastInsets = insets;
            requestLayout();
        }
        return insets.consumeSystemWindowInsets();
    }

    class OnOffsetChangedListener implements AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener {

        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {


        }
    }
}
```

please help I am new to `cllapsetoolbarlayout`, if something not clear tell me please, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the hack here is to make `ImageView` on top of other layouts be giving it higher **z-index**

```
final ImageView fab = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fab);
ViewCompat.setTranslationZ(fab, 100);
```

Comment: thanks a lot that help me, actually I tried bringToFront but that didnt help, your solution is works perfectly